# Views generating JSON output

Tags: 7, views

I want to pull a JSON file out of a view that has images. This is similar to the way views_datasource works in D6.  I am not a drupal coder, but I would like to give this a try.  but I am guessing that is would be something like  http://mearra.com/blogs/juha-niemi/drupal-7-custom-node-view-modes#comment-218

but I would like to make this a module as much as possible.
any sample code, examples would be great.
thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is now a Drupal 7 version of [Views Datasource](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource). Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... is a set of plugins for Drupal Views for rendering content in a number of shareable, reusable formats based on XML, JSON and XHTML. These formats allow content in a Drupal site to be easily used as data sources for Semantic Web clients and web mash-ups. Views Datasource plugins output content from node lists created in the Drupal Views interface in a variety of formats - XML data documents using schemas like OPML and Atom, RDF data documents using a vocabulary like FOAF, JSON data documents in a format like Exhibit JSON, and XHTML data documents using a microformat like hCard.
>
> The project consists of 4 Views style plugins (and related row plugins):
>
> - views_xml - Output as raw XML, OPML, and Atom;
> - views_json - Output as Simile/Exhibit JSON, Canonical JSON, JSONP/JSON in script;
> - views_rdf- Output as FOAF, SIOC, and DOAP;
> - views_xhtml - Output as hCard, hCalendar, and Geo.

Answer (score 1):

The referenced article is about *view mode* which have nothing to do with Views and almost none with the output format of a page.

Note there is an [ongoing effort](https://drupal.org/node/981810) to port Views Datasource to Drupal 7 with [a dev. version](http://windmill.sk/project/module/views_datasource) available outside of Drupal.org.

Answer (score 0):

[views json](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_json)

> This module is meant for people doing heavy-duty JS work. Knowledge
>   of JSON, jQuery, and a bit of Views internals is needed to fully
>   utilize this module.

[views datasource](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource)

> Views Datasource is a set of plugins for Drupal Views for rendering
>   content in a number of shareable, reusable formats based on XML, JSON
>   and XHTML. These formats allow content in a Drupal site to be easily
>   used as data sources for Semantic Web clients and web mash-ups. Views
>   Datasource plugins output content from node lists created in the
>   Drupal Views interface in a variety of formats - XML data documents
>   using schemas like OPML and Atom, RDF data documents using a
>   vocabulary like FOAF, JSON data documents in a format like Exhibit
>   JSON, and XHTML data documents using a microformat like hCard.
>
> Views Datasource can be thought of as a userland complement to the
>   work going on in the Services and RDF APIs as a site operator only
>   needs to know Views to be able to create datasources in the different
>   formats.